# FAQ Toggle Arrow Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

Hello I have below code for FAQ Toggle but the issue is when I click on any question it slides and show the answer perfectly but the all arrows in all question triggers.

```
<div class="faqbox" id="faq-list">
    <div class="qblock">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</h2>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip.</p>      
        </div><!-- answer -->
    </div><!-- qblock -->

    <div class="qblock">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</h2>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip.</p>      
        </div><!-- answer -->
    </div><!-- qblock -->


</div><!-- faqbox -->
```

This is the JS

```
function toggleFaqArrow(){    
    $('.qblock .arrow').toggleClass('rotate'); 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qblock h2').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
        toggleFaqArrow();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toggleFaqArrow()` function targets **all** `arrow` class elements inside **all** `qblock` class elements. You only want to toggle the `rotate` class of the [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with class `arrow` of the `h2` element clicked.

To achieve this, change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qblock h2').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
        $(this).siblings('.arrow').toggleClass('rotate');
    });
});
```

Comment: one more thing. You see the click on on h2. I want to make the arrow click able too. Means If we click anywhere on the question it should drop down. Here is JSfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/sam53/pt8dkm54/2/

Comment: @NaveedJavaid In your case I would drop the `arrow` span and just set the [:after](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:after) pseudo selectors to display and transform the arrow. Like in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pt8dkm54/3/).

Comment: Thanks @ZiNNED I have modified the code and now it perfect.